# OpenVPN to home LAN for RDP

Tags: openvpn

Before I waste time going into configuring it: if I route a OpenVPN connection from a remote location to my home LAN over tcp 443, will I still be able to do things like RDP? The OpenVPN server is a desktop not a router not a DHCP server.

Normally doing something like RDP to home LAN involves forwarding ports on router but in this routed VPN connection I only want to open 443. Do I have to port forward on the router the RDP port or just ensure the firewall is allowing that port on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only port you need to `forward` on your `router` is the port for `openvpn` server (default: UDP 1194).  You do **not** need to open `RDP` port (default: TCP 3389) on your router becuase RDP packets will travel via the VPN.

Comment: I thought as much but I thought I'd check, thank you.